# Constructing a dynamic LINQ query with several joins and unknown selects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a pair of tables with a one `Account` to many `Attribute` relationship. The `Account` table contains several sets of entries from discrete sources, and they have relationships through various strategies involving their related `Attribute`s. The input expected would be random `Attribute.Name` values from one or more of the `Account` groups, I will perform the required joins back to the same table.

At runtime, I want to iteratively generate the query with expression trees. The problem I have is the entity type changes and continuously expands (all properties are string), therefor I do not know how to approach this. Building the query in SQL is trivial, in similar problems using `Dapper` with raw SQL statements, I use a generic entity type with properties named `p0` through `p100` and use reflection and/or `AutoMapper` to obtain the final desired graph.

For a given `Attribute.Name`, there may be several values so I would expect to see a subsequent result sets for that instance of the value (ie the same account works for two companies).

**How the minimal working example differs from the actual**

1. In the working model, I won't know the attributes required until runtime. I have hardcoded "giveName", "sn" and "company" so the repro would compile.
2. In the working model, I will add a predicate on the first `Account` context instance to filter only those accounts which have an `Attribute` with a given name and value.
3. In the working model, I will add another instance of the `Account` context to find accounts which were not included in the above based on an `Attribute` with a given name and value. I will then join this back to the initial query.
4. In the working model, I may repeat the join above with yet another set of discrete accounts if the user asks for specific attributes.

I am unclear how to define the query return type such that it may continuously expand in scope. The return type is **not** and `Account`, it starts off as one but each result set will include one or more related accounts.

```
// Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.4
// Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 2.1.4
// System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.5.0
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AccountId))]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.Name)
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Account)
            .WithMany(p => p.Attributes)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.Name);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.Value);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase("db")
            .Options;

        using (var context = new MyContext(options))
        {
            context.Accounts.AddRange(
                new Account
                {
                    Name = "John Doe",
                    Attributes = new List<Attribute>
                    {
                        new Attribute { Name = "giveName", Value = "John" },
                        new Attribute { Name = "sn", Value = "Doe" },
                        new Attribute { Name = "company", Value = "My Company" },
                    }
                }, new Account
                {
                    Name = "Jane Doe",
                    Attributes = new List<Attribute>
                    {
                        new Attribute { Name = "giveName", Value = "Jane" },
                        new Attribute { Name = "sn", Value = "Doe" },
                        new Attribute { Name = "company", Value = "Another Company" },
                    }
                });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new MyContext(options))
        {
            var query =
                from account in context.Accounts
                join attr1 in context.Attributes
                    on new{ accountId = account.Id, name = "giveName" } equals new { accountId = attr1.AccountId, name = attr1.Name }
                    into attr1Grp
                join attr2 in context.Attributes
                    on new { accountId = account.Id, name = "sn" } equals new { accountId = attr2.AccountId, name = attr2.Name }
                    into attr2Grp
                join attr3 in context.Attributes
                    on new { accountId = account.Id, name = "company" } equals new { accountId = attr3.AccountId, name = attr3.Name }
                    into attr3Grp
                from a1 in attr1Grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from a2 in attr2Grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from a3 in attr3Grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    Account = account.Name,
                    GivenName = a1.Value,
                    SurName = a2.Value,
                    Company = a3.Value
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using code first and relations are declared in your model builder I don't see a reason to make all those joints in your query. Instead of lazy loading, you'd be able to include related entities and collections.

Comment: The reason is stated in the first paragraph, imagine 300 accounts in the table, 100 have an attribute type "hcmId", another 100 have an attribute type "hcxId" and the last 100 have an attribute type "employeeId". The accounts correlate by the value of these three attribute types. Now, once I have the 3 way set, I need to access various other attribute types from each of the 3 accounts (the name from the first, the company from the second, the location from the third). There are far too many accounts to do this outside of SQL as the users view supports paging and filtering.

Comment: This is the type of job I'd write a stored procedure for.

Comment: @Ritmo2k, following your requirement the *"query ending up in a usable result such as a string array"* seems to be `var accounts = context.Accounts.Include(a => a.Attributes)`. Basically this is all you need. It works with unknown number of attributes, returns a collection of accounts and everything gets mapped correctly.

Comment: I have updated the question to incorporate the clarity in my first comment.